# Help with a proof in discrete math.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to figure out this problems to no avail.

Problem $1$: Show that there are infinitely many natural numbers $x,y,z$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{z}.$$

Thank you all! I apologize if I have ignored some of the etiquettes of this community. I am a college student and this is my first time on this site. I will make sure that I follow the rules on my future posts.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain where you're having trouble?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: first find one solution x,y,z. Now what if you multiply all of these numbers by the same integer, say 2?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an infinite number of triples that satisfies the condition:
$$
\left\{\left.(x,y,z)=\left(2^n,2^n,2^{n-1}\right)\right|n\in \mathbb N\right\}\\
\frac 1{2^n}+\frac 1{2^n}=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

An explicit example is $x=2n,y=2n,z=n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing what happens if $x=y$ and if $x$ (and thus $y$) is any even natural number. You will always get $\frac{1}{z}$ for a natural number $z$. Why? How is $z$ related to $x$ in this case? Conclude that you have an infinite set of natural numbers to supply for your solution.